# Safari Developer Tools keeps crashing on open

Tags: iphone, safari, safari-web-inspector

Whenever I use Safari Developer Tools to inspect an app I'm developing, it crashes almost immediately, which makes debugging near to impossible for my IOS app...

Currently using Safari Version 11.1 (13605.1.33.1.2), Mac OSX High Siera 10.13.4 (17E199).

I have tried googling this, and it looks like it used to be an issue, but it was fixed in an earlier version but has popped back up for me. I've tried multiple cables, different ports on my mac, and it always syncs the phone and shows up in the toolbar, but once I click it, it disappears, and crashes the dev tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is linked to when the iPhone is fully charged. I am not sure why this is the case, but when it is fully charged, the computer must send some signal to the phone, because it no longer works. If I let my phone run low on battery, and try developer tools, 9 times out of 10 it works - until it recharges fully.

Comment: I spent some time playing games with my iPhone... But, no, it didn't work for me. :(

Comment: Try setting the phone on a flat surface, and not moving it too much. Unplug the cable from the computer, plug it back in, wait a few seconds and then try to check and see if the iPhone is an option. I’ve noticed it’s pretty finicky if you move the phone cable too much.

Comment: I have also recently discovered that if you go into your phone settings (General > Reset > Reset Location & Privacy), and reset the location & privacy settings, the application will not crash for some time. This is quite annoying to have to do constantly but seems to be the only solution that works consistently.

Comment: This absolutely worked for me on an iPhone 5s. Ran the battery down with you tube on hd and the flashlight.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but it didn't solve it on my iPad.

Answer (score 1):

I have turned off all apps that I did not need and it started to work. It is also somehow related to the load of the Mac's CPU.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same strange problem, and find out because a blank:

```
<canvas> </canvas>
```

When I remove it, the developer tools won't auto close any more.

```
<canvas></canvas>
```

If this not working, try to remove some part of your code, to find out.